# having problem in importing pandas in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, import

This is popping up after I run the code `import pandas as pd`

```
  NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
    ----> 1 import pandas as pd


c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     49 import pandas.core.config_init
     50 
---> 51 from pandas.core.api import (
     52     # dtype
     53     Int8Dtype,

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py in <module>
     13 

enter code here

     14 from pandas.core.algorithms import factorize, unique, value_counts
---> 15 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
     16 from pandas.core.arrays.boolean import BooleanDtype
     17 from pandas.core.arrays.floating import Float32Dtype, Float64Dtype

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py in <module>
      5 )
      6 from pandas.core.arrays.boolean import BooleanArray
----> 7 from pandas.core.arrays.categorical import Categorical
      8 from pandas.core.arrays.datetimes import DatetimeArray
      9 from pandas.core.arrays.floating import FloatingArray

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py in <module>
----> 1 from csv import QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
      2 from functools import partial
      3 import operator
      4 from shutil import get_terminal_size
      5 from typing import Dict, Hashable, List, Sequence, Type, TypeVar, Union, cast

~\OneDrive\Desktop\python\Ardent\csv.py in <module>
   1175   {
   1176    "cell_type": "code",
-> 1177    "execution_count": null,
   1178    "id": "authorized-neighbor",
   1179    "metadata": {},

NameError: name 'null' is not defined

**
```

Comment: Naming your Python script `csv.py` is dangerous as it shadows the built-in `csv` module. And your `csv.py` script seems to contain JSON. Please re-name that script in `~\OneDrive\Desktop\python\Ardent\csv.py` to something else, and re-run.

Comment: Your csv.py script is the problem (it is invalid), not Pandas.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem sorted. I wasted my entire day in this stupid problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you assigned a `null` value to a key in a dictionary inside csv.py.

Is `null` a variable?

If you want to assign an ["empty"/"null" value in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None), you should use `None`. `null` is not a type in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import json
mydict = json.dumps(data)
```

Whatever data you are converting into dict make sure it should be json.dumps() before print or process otherwise the null will be treated as variable.